# String input with getchar

Tags: c, printf, getchar

I've a little problem with my code, why when I use printf on string1 (last line), it doesn't give me what I wrote for this variable ?

For example if I wrote : asdfgh, string1 give me something weird like : @>>..

Any idea ?

Thanks for help.

```
 int main()
{
    int length;
    int i = 0;
    char string1[100];
    printf("Please enter the length of the two strings\n");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    printf("\nPlease enter the first string\n");
    while((string1[i] = getchar())!='\n')
        i++ ;
    getchar();
    printf("\nString 1 : %c", string1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you mean `%s` in `printf("\nString 1 : %s", string1);` also don't forget to put null-terminattor.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code, but the most immediate is that your string is not null terminated, and you use `%s` to `printf()` strings, not `%c`.

Comment: Thx, I modified the %, and I asked for help for terminate the string. It's the first I use getchar.. It's a little bit problematic for me :s

Comment: Another major problem is that the `while` loop reads the remainder of the first line, where the user typed in the length and pressed enter. Anything the user types after the second prompt appears will not be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few problems there:

1) Should use `%s` for printing string.
2) Terminate the string with NULL terminator (It's not a string until then ;)
3) use a standard prototype for main(), such as: `int main(void)`

Comment: Hey! Thx for your answer, you re right. Null terminator is '\0' yeah ?
Where can I find help with this ? Because in this case, I don't know how to terminate the string..
Thx.

Comment: Yes `'\0'` or just `0` will do. After the loop add: `string1[i]='\0';` Remember you can only input 99 chars (+1 for NULL). Otherwise, you'll run into more problems.

Comment: Ah! Yes of course, I wrote string1[100]='\0' and not i ! (My mistake).

Now my code is :

`int main(void)
{
    int length;
    int i = 0;
    char string1[101];
    printf("Please enter the length of the two strings\n");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    printf("\nPlease enter the first string\n");
    while((string1[i] = getchar())!='\n')
        i++ ;
        string1[i] = '\0';
    getchar();
    printf("\nString 1 : %s", string1);

    return 0;
}`

Comment: I dont think you should have the last getchar() after you have put in the NULL terminator, I guess it confuses the input buffer.

Comment: Ok, there's another problem.  You need use another `getchar()` right after the scanf() call to consume the `\n` left, which makes the while loop condition fail right away without entering the loop at all. TBH, I don't get the point reading `length` since you don't use it anywhere. Besides, scanf() is not a friendly input function, on which you should read about more. Here's one: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: @Blue Moon you are right :)) just have to move the getchar() here ! Its working now. Thanks.

And about the `length`, I will need it to continue my program.

Its possible to create string1[length] instead of string1[101] yeah ? Because in fact, it s the user who decides the length of my string1.. It will be better I think.

Comment: @user3605367 Unless you have support for [VLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (c99 or later), you can't do `string1[length]`. If it's not supported then you will need a [dynamic allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Usage_example).

Comment: @Blue moon Ok I will read it :). And my last little question : If I want to request that the user writes an other string, the getchar() just after the scanf won't be enough I guess ?

Comment: That extra `getchar()` to consume `\n` is needed whenever the format string concerned doesn't consume read it/clear the input buffer. There's no general answer to that (whether you'll need more getchar()). You should avoid using scanf() if possible. More about in the link I posted before.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
    int length;
    int i = 0;
    int ch;
    char string1[100];
    printf("Please enter the length of the two strings\n");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    getchar();
    printf("\nPlease enter the first string\n");
    /* use null for termination of string */
    /* Press Ctrl+d to end your input */
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
            string1[i++] = ch;

    }
    string1[i] = '\0';
    /* USE %s to print whole string */
    printf("\nString 1 : %s\n", string1);

    return 0;
  }
```

Hope this will solve your problem